# while loop not breaking from bufferedReader from docker events in java

Tags: java, docker, bufferedreader

Basically, I want to execute a docker events command which gives me a bunch of events from past 15min, I have written a code I'm able to get events everything fine, but here the `while` loop is breaking out and coming out it goes on running inside the loop.
I tried so many changes but not working out. Once check that picture in that cursor is blinking not stopping, manual I should press <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd>

```
try {
    String[] cmd
            = {IMetricsCommands.bin,
                IMetricsCommands.C,
                "docker events --format '{{.Status}}:-{{.Actor.Attributes.name}}' --since '15m'"};
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    process.getOutputStream().close();
    bufferedReaderObj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    AE.logger.stat(ModId.AECORE, "CORE: Command executed for docker container Events Collection");
} catch (Exception e) {

}
String sLine = "";
if ((sLine = bufferedReaderObj.readLine()) == null) {
} else {
    while ((sLine = bufferedReaderObj.readLine()) != null && !sLine.isEmpty()) {
            String[] events = sLine.split(":-");
            if (events[0].contains(":")) {
                String event = events[0].split(":")[0];
                if (eventType.contains(event)) {
                    EventMap.put(event, sLine);
                }
            } else {
                if (eventType.contains(events[0])) {
                    EventMap.put(events[0], events[1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: The read loop won't end until the peer closes its output, typically when it exits, or sends a blank line, but why you would want to stop on a blank line is a mystery, as indeed is why you would send one in the first place. But you've thrown away the first line of the input. Get rid of the `if` before the `while`.

Comment: @user207421 yes understood about if, i will delete that line. so i don't have any option??

Comment: Any option for what?

Comment: For breaking and coming out of the loop?

Comment: For breaking out of the loop when? Just add another condition. Unclear what you're asking.